# better code for 2 for loop?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript

I looking at a alternative coding which use two for loop, my code is require to overwrite the value in array b into a if b has a larger value than a, after break and loop a will continue point to the next index until it has the next 'mm' value while the loop b will resume from where it was "break"

Is there any cleaner code?

```
var a = ['100','200','300','400','500'];
var ma = ['-','mm','-','-','mm'];

var b = ['100','150','160','200','250','300','500','600'];
var mb = ['-','-','-','-','mm','','','mm'];

for loop a
  if(ma[]=='mm')
  {
    for loop b
      if(ma[]=='mm')
      {
        if (a < b) {
         break;
        }
      }
  }
```

Comment: I bet no one will answer that :) Can you explain what you need more clearly?

Comment: Doesn't make sense. Especially second one of these : if(ma[]=='mm') Why would you be checking that again, in case of a false positive the first time you check it? for loop a if(ma[]=='mm') // you check here 1st { for loop b if(ma[]=='mm') // we check it again? huh?? when does this ever eval to false? { if (a < b) { break; } } } Is that supposed to be something else? Please clarify :)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I think you are trying to say, but I may need more information.

> I am looking for an alternative way to
>   code my nested for loops. My method
>   requires one to overwrite the value in
>   array a with the value in array b,
>
> > if a is less than b
>
> After the `break` from the inner loop,
>   a will continue to increment until the
>   next *mm* value and b will continue to
>   increment until the next *mm* value.
>   So changes to `a` occur only if
>
> 1. The value at the current index in ma equals mm which equals the value of
>      the current index in mb
> 2. `a` is less than `b`, assign the value at b[j] to a[i].
>      Then the `b` inner loop breaks and we
>      continue along in `a` and start over

Assuming that is what you want, then you just need to keep track of j before the break

So then when you are iterating

```
for (j = setIndex; j < b.length ; j++)
```

before the break, within the conditional you can say

```
setindex = j+1;
```

And the next time the loop starts it should start from where it left off.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the reason you are finding it hard to solve this problem is because you are finding it difficult to define the problem. As phwd said, if you could please clarify your question we may be able to help.

If you clarify your question, you may find that you can answer it yourself without help. This is programming.